# Need help. Can't resolve getting wrong url

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I have problem with url in my project.
I've new to programming and I'm learning Django through Django tutorial on official website. In part 4 of the tutorial, there's a section which shows how to use generic views. 
I have checked my code few times and everything seems to be exactly the same as it is in tutorial.
However, when I click on a link for detail.html (on index page) I'm getting a 404 error with Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/1//
I can't figure out how come I get this request url (ending with second forward slash).
What am I doing wrong?
Everything worked just fine when I used functions that returned i.e render(request, "polls/detail.html", context)

Here's debug error explanation:
"Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
[name='index']
<int:pk>/ [name='detail']
<int:pk>/results/ [name='results']
<int:question_id>/vote/ [name='vote']
admin/
```

The current path, 1//, didn't match any of these."

Down below is my code for index.html, project/urls.py, app/urls.py and app/views.py

project/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

app/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name="results"),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name="vote"),
]
```

app/views.py

```
from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, Question


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = "latest_question_list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.order_by("-pub_date")[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'
```

index.html body:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}

<ul>

    {% for question in latest_question_list %}

        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}/">
        {{ question.question_text }}</a>
        </li>

    {% endfor  %}

</ul>

{% else %}

<p>No polls are available.</p>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: try to remove the slash from the href `<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}/"`.

Comment: my, oh my...
Thank you! :D